# Add custom delete behavior to some objects with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'd like to add some custom behavior to some SQLALchemy models when they are deleted, e.g. when a User is deleted, all his Posts are deleted too (easy to do using `cascade`), but I'd like to call a custom routine on each of those Posts when they are deleted.

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    posts = db.relationship('Post', back_populates='user', cascade="save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan")


class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    text = db.Column(db.String(140))
    filename = db.Column(db.String(60))

    user = db.relationship('User', back_populates='posts')
```

Let's say I delete a user with `db.session.delete(user)` and I commit this, I'd like a function to be called automatically for each related Post to remove the file `post.filename`, so that after this `db.session.delete(user)` and commit, all local files related to all user's posts are removed.

Ideally it would perfect just to have to add a method in the `Post` class that is called automatically when a post is marked for deletion.
Something like:

```py
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    text = db.Column(db.String(140))
    filename = db.Column(db.String(60))

    user = db.relationship('User', back_populates='posts')

    def on_delete(self):
        os.remove(self.filename)
```

I insist on the fact that this `on_delete` method should be called automatically when a post is marked for deletion.
Is it possible to achieve such a result?

Comment: Maybe registering a handler to the [persistent_to_deleted](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.persistent_to_deleted) event?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `persistent_to_deleted` event didn't do the job, but the `after_delete` one works perfectly. Thank for your help ! :)

Comment: Glad you worked it out!